# Golang: Is it safe to say that if a struct implements a method then it satisfies all interfaces that define that method's signature?

Tags: docker, go

In the docker source repo,
there exists an interface in [image/backend.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/server/router/image/backend.go#L33):

```
type imageBackend interface {
    ....
    ImagesPrune(pruneFilters filters.Args) (*types.ImagesPruneReport, error)
}
```

and, there is an implementation in [daemon/prune.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/daemon/prune.go#L85-L190):

```
func (daemon *Daemon) ImagesPrune(pruneFilters filters.Args) (*types.ImagesPruneReport, error) {
    ... implementation details ...
}
```

Does this mean it's correct to say that `Daemon` implements the `imageBackend` interface?

**Background:**
I'm trying to understand how calling `docker system prune` cmd invokes the `ImagesPrune` function in `daemon.go`. I could trace the code flow as:

> `cli/../system/prune.go
>   -> cli/../prune/prune.go
>   -> cli/../image/prune.go
>   -> client/image_prune.go
>   -> api/server/..image/image_routes.go
>   -> api/server/../image/backend.go 
>   -----> ??? ----> daemon/prune.go`

I don't know what comes in the `???` section above.

Comment: In this case, `*Deamon` implements imageBackend not `Deamon`. In Go, both are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `Daemon` does implement the `imageBackend` interface (as pointed out in the comments, it's actually the `*Daemon` type that implements the interface). All of `imageBackend`'s methods are implemented in various source code files inside the `daemon` package (mostly the `image_*.go` ones).

In the `image_routes.go` the `postImagesPrune` [method is called](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/server/router/image/image_routes.go#L329), which in turn [calls the](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/server/router/image/image_routes.go#L339) `ImagesPrune` method of `s.backend`. `s` is a pointer to the instance of `imageRouter`.

```
type imageRouter struct {
    backend Backend
    decoder httputils.ContainerDecoder
    routes  []router.Route
}
```

This `imageRouter` instance is initialized with `backend` set to an instance of `Daemon` in `cmd/dockerd/daemon.go` [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/cmd/dockerd/daemon.go#L484).

So when `s.backend.ImagesPrune` is called, it is running the `ImagesPrune` method of the Docker Daemon, which as you point out above is in `daemon/prune.go`.

Comment: I think in this case, `*Deamon`(pointer of `Deamon` type) implements `imageBackend` interface not `Deamon`.